# How to tell, whether a C++ proposal is accepted or not?

Tags: c++, standards

Let's take [P1907](https://wg21.link/P1907) as an example. Is it accepted into the C++ standard? To which version? When?

Comment: Not a real answer, but you can reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support. Search for the proposal number, see if it's listed.

Comment: You can also find out bit here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Papers can be tracked here.

https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues

Entering `is:issue P1907` into the search box produces:

[P1907](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/653) (closed)

and

[P1907R1](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3441) (merged)

***Alternatively,***

If you use [Slack](https://slack.com/), you can join the C++ slack at [**cpplang.slack.com**](https://cpplang.slack.com/) and privately message any paper name to **@npaperbot** to get information about it.

Answer (score 2):

The papers are managed on Github:
https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues?q=

https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/653

You can also look into the compiler compatibility page of cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20